# Name of the song that Conan played in Season 1 Episode 11: Moonlight Sonata Murder Case

Tags: detective-conan

What is the name of the song that Conan played in Season 1 Episode 11: Moonlight Sonata Murder Case at 08:27? [Here is the link to the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_6Q-BMJomws#t=8m27s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The song is "Shave and a Haircut, Two Bits".